# Gtk+3 Css provider don't works

Tags: css, c, gtk3

I'm trying to pu image in background of GtkBox with css provider, and label text style, but nothing happens. I tried with so many different ways.

Here is my custom.css:

```
GtkBox#Home_PrincipalScreen_table{
    background-image: url("background.png");
}

GtkLabel#Home_Cooling_Tunnel1_Cooler_label1{
    color: white;
}

GtkLabel#label_Avg_Temp_value{
    color: red;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 25px;
}
GtkButton{color: blue;
    font-size: 25px
}
```

And here is my .c file:

```
    GFile *file= g_file_new_for_path("custom.css");
    GtkCssProvider *css_provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    if(!gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(css_provider, file, &error))
    {
        g_warning( "%s", error->message );
        g_free( error );
        return( 1 );
    }
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(gdk_screen_get_default(), css_provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

UPDATE:

Widgets change it proprieties like GtkButton example, but specific widget like Home_PrincipalScreen_table don't change.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that i don't define in glade the widget name. Css provider isn't defined by ID but by widget name. 
So, i changed `GtkBox#Home_PrincipalScreen_table` to `#Background` and define the widget name as `Background` and works...